# Mobile app menu at the bottom of the page easier to access?

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, menu

I saw the new user interface changes made to the New Words with Friends app, and they have placed the 'hamburger' menu icon at the bottom of the page, and moved the controls for the different views of the application to the top. I think it is an interesting design that also incorporates some changes to the interaction design and process flows (for example, now you have to go to the menu to pass on your turn).

I am wondering if in the age where a lot of navigation items are tightly clustered at the top of the screen, moving the menu to the bottom of the screen will actually help ease the clutter a little bit more.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows Phone they are doing something like this.

- The very minimal indication of a menu is ellipsis (...) in the bottom right corner of the screen. Clicking on this slides up the menu.
- The slightly more prominent menu consists of a black bar along the bottom with a selection of simple icons and no text (to access very commonly used functions), and the ellipsis again. Clicking the ellipsis displays text description of the icons, and any further menu options.

This approach seems logical to me, as it allows me to focus on the content first, and *then* see what menu options I have to do actions on it.

Comment: Yes, I've seen them on the Windows Mobile OS interface. However, the convention for '...' seems to be like a 'more' rather than a menu, which got me a little bit confused initially. It is also interesting for phones with a built-in menu button when there's another menu button on the interface.

Comment: @MichaelLai The "..." menu is "built in" in the sense that it is a component that you can choose to use, it isn't "built in" in the sense that it is displayed by the OS for all apps. For example, the Facebook app developed by Microsoft uses the usual top bar menu. The "..." isn't used at all.